# Не открываются представления в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

При попытке открыть любое представление (cshtml) в проекте вылетает следующая ошибка "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта" (Рис. 1)

[image: Рис. 1]

В новом проекте и новом представлении та же ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думал уже переустанавливать VS, но нашел решение необходимо удалить каталог **ComponentModelCache** путь C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

[Источник информации](https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/276#issuecomment-166650817)